# Dini condition application doubt

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

**Dini condition**: There is a function that satisfies the Dini condition so it means: $\phi(t)=\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{t}$ so $\int_\limits{0}^{\alpha}|\phi(t)|dt<\infty$.

**Absolutely continuous**: $f$ is also absolutely continuous which translates into: $f\in [a,b]$,$\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ such that $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\subset[a,b]\:\:\:\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]<\delta\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(\beta_i-\alpha_i)|<\epsilon$

**Notes**: $\int_\limits{0}^{\alpha}\frac{|f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)|}{t} dt\leqslant \int_\limits{0}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{t}\int_\limits{x_0}^{x_0+t}|f'(y)|dydt\leqslant\mu\int_\limits{0}^{\alpha} 1 dt=\mu\delta$.

**Questions:**

**1)** As far as I understand the absolute continuity implies that $f'(t)\leqslant M$ where $M$ is a constant. Does $\mu$ incorporate the derivative or is $|f'(y)\leqslant 1|$?

**2)**  Considering $\int_\limits{0}^{\alpha}\frac{|f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)|}{t} dt\leqslant \int_\limits{0}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{t}\int_\limits{x_0}^{x_0+t}|f'(y)|dydt$. What is the reason of this first inequality? It seems to me as if it was instead an equality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, $f$ absolutely continuous does not imply that $f'$ is bounded;  in fact $f'$ can be any integrable function. That inequality you ask about would be equality if the absolute value signs were not there; you can certainly have $|\int f'|<\int|f'|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for your comment! What do you think about how the author got the constants in order major the integral?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. (From  your post it's not at all clear to me what is assumed, where. Is he trying to show that absolute continuity implies a Dini condition, or what?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich            I am sorry but that is not stated. I need to figure it out. This is the all information I have. What do you think?